# Why I'm getting 0 results when fuzziness is more than 2?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `elastic search 7.6.2`

I have index with the following mapping:

```
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "content": {"type": "text"},
            }
        }
```

with 3 documents:

1. michael jordan and scottie pippen - NBA is a professional basketball league in North America.
2. michael jordan and scottie pippen - National Basketball Association
3. michael jordan and scottie pippen

I'm running the following simple query:

```
  "query":{
              "bool":{
                 "must":[
                    {
                       "span_near":{
                          "clauses":[
                             {
                                "span_multi":{
                                   "match":{
                                      "fuzzy":{
                                         "content":{
                                            "value":"hael",
                                            "fuzziness":4
                                         }
                                      }
                                   }
                                }
                             },                           
                          ],
                          "slop":1,
                          "in_order": "true"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
    }
```

And I'm getting 0 results.

1. Why I'm not getting results ? (The value `hael` has 3 missing letters, and the `fuzziness` is 4) ?
2. What is the meaning of `slop` (at the end of the query) ? (It seems that it doesn't do nothing)

Comment: which word would be closer to `hael` ?

Comment: Michael (***hael)